# How do we store dispatch results to variables inside of our Actions?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs, immer.js

I need to handle some pretty simple logic inside of my state and am having a really hard time piecing together what needs to be done and at the moment I can't figure out how to store the results of an action in a variable.  Take the following action for example.

```
@Action(HandleProduct)
    private handleProduct(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {category, product}: HandleProduct){

        let getCategory: number;
        let getProduct:  number;

        ctx.dispatch(new FindCategory(category)).pipe(tap(result => getCategory = result));
        ctx.dispatch(new FindProduct(getCategory, product)).pipe(tap(result => getProduct = result));



        if(getProduct !== -1){ ctx.dispatch(new SetCurrentProduct(getCategory, getProduct)); }

        else{

            ctx.dispatch(new FetchProduct(category, product)).pipe(tap(result => {
                ctx.setState((state: ProductDataModel)=>{
                    state.cattegories[getCategory].products.push(result);
                    return state;
                });
            }));

            ctx.dispatch(new FindProduct(getCategory, product)).pipe(tap(result => getProduct = result));
            ctx.dispatch(new SetCurrentProduct(getCategory, getProduct));
        }
    }
```

I get errors from this function telling me

> type void is not assignable to type number

in regards to setting the results to the `getCategory` and `getProduct` variables.

Overall what I'm trying to do is

- 1. Search inside of respective category of the state for the product.
- 2. If product data exists set data to "current product" property on state.

or

- 3a. If product doesn't exist send API request to backend.
- 3b. Set product data as "current product".
- 3c. Add data to "products" list in respective category inside the state.

the way I have my other functions set up goes as follows

```
@Action(InitProductState)
    public initProductState(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>){
        //console.log('InitProductState triggered');
        if(ctx.getState().categories.length < 1){
            //console.log('if condition triggered');

            return this.dataService.fetchProductInitData().pipe(tap((result) =>{

                //console.log('data service triggered');

                const categoryList: ProductCategoryModel[] = [];

                result.forEach(a=>{
                    const categoryObj: ProductCategoryModel = {
                        productCategoryId: a.productCategoryId,
                        name: a.name,
                        description: a.description,
                        products: []
                    };

                    categoryList.push(categoryObj);
                });
                ctx.patchState({ categories:[...categoryList]});
                //console.log(ctx.getState());
            }));
        }
    }

    @Action(FindCategory)
    private searchForCattegory(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {category}: FindCategory):number{
        return ctx.getState().cattegories.findIndex(a=>a.productCattegoryId === category) as number;
    }

    @Action(FindProduct)
    private searchForProduct(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {category, product}: FindProduct): number{
        return ctx.getState().cattegories[category].products.findIndex(a=> a.productId === product) as number;
    }

    @Action(SetCurrentProduct)
    private setCurrentProduct(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {category, product}: SetCurrentProduct){
        ctx.setState((state:ProductDataModel)=>{
            state.currentProduct = state.cattegories[category].products[product];
            return state;
        });
    }

    @Action(FetchItem)
    private fetchProductData({category, product}: FetchItem){
        return this.dataService.fetchProductData(category, product);
    }

    @Action(FetchProduct)
    public fetchProduct(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {cattegory, product}: FetchProduct){
        const state = ctx.getState();

        if(state.cattegories.length < 1){ ctx.dispatch(new InitProductState()); }

        ctx.dispatch(new HandleProduct(cattegory, product));
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors in regards to any of those but just thought I'd show how it's set up just incase there is something wrong with it.  The only solution I can think of is creating the variables on the state and using selectors to view them but that feels like extreme overkill for something I just need to refer to in one action, plus from what I've learned so far using the state for things like that really isn't suggested.  How can I set this up to work?

For more insight into the shape of my state here's my interfaces.

```
export interface ShortDescriptionCore  { description       : string; }
export interface ProductIdCore         { productId         : string; }
export interface ProductCategoryIdCore { productCategoryId : string; }
export interface InstructionTargetCore { instructionKey    : string; }
export interface NameCore              { name              : string; }


export interface ProductDataItem extends ProductIdCore, NameCore, ShortDescriptionCore, InstructionTargetCore{
    models: ModelDataItem[];
}

export interface ProductCategoryItem extends ProductCategoryIdCore, NameCore, ShortDescriptionCore{}

export interface CategoryInitIndex extends ProductCategoryIdCore{ products?: ProductDataItem[]; }

export interface ProductCategoryModel extends ProductCategoryItem{ products: ProductDataItem[]; }

export interface ProductDataModel{
    categories: ProductCategoryModel[];
    currentProduct: ProductDataItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simplify this down you might find its a bit easier to manage.

There's a few changes you might consider:

1. Lose the actions for `FindXXX` and just grab them directly from the current state, rather than dispatching an `Action`.
2. Then do a patch straight away if you find the product, otherwise call the API to get it and then patch it into the state.

See the example below (adapted from your code sample).

```
    @Action(HandleProduct)
    handleProduct(ctx:StateContext<ProductDataModel>, {category, product}: HandleProduct){

    const currentState = ctx.getState();

    // Search directly in current state (don't need to dispatch Actions for this)
    const categoryMatch = currentState.categories.find(cat => cat.productCategoryId === category);
    const productMatch = categoryMatch.products.find(p => p.productId === product); 

    // Found a product, so use it
    if(productMatch){ 
       ctx.patchState({ currentProduct: productMatch });
    }
    else { // No match, so fetch it
       return this.dataService.fetchProduct(category, product)
              .pipe(
                 tap(result => { // Add product and flag as current
                     // Need to update the correct category product list (deep clone)
                     const updatedCategories= [...categories];
                     const index = updateCategories.findIndex(cat => cat.productCategoryId === category);
                                               updatedCategories[index].products = [...updatedCategories[index].products, result];
                     // Patch update the product list and the current product.
                     ctx.patchState({ 
                         categories: updatedCategories,
                         currentProduct: result 
                       });
                    })
                  );
        }));
    }
```

3. For the initial load of data i.e. `InitProductState`, either load that using the `ngxsOnInit` lifecycle hook, or trigger that via some `Action` that is dispatched when the data is required (usually when that page is loaded / navigated to).

The example code I've added you can see is a bit clunky to try and patch changes to the nested product value within a category list. I've found using NGXS for a while now that if you can avoid these nested structures it'll make development easier.

You might want to consider flattening your state model structure further, so that the list of products is a top level collection (same as categories) (even if your API returns it nested). Then when you update/add a product you can patch a simple array, rather than a nested structured.  It'll make your edit/patch action code a lot simpler for maintaining immutable state.  You can use `Selectors` if you want to group/filter the data before it is consumed by the Angular components.

Comment: THANKS!!!.  The reason I'm doing it this way is because each product also has multiple models and sizes which are subject to grow.  Besides that every example and tutorial I come across is so simple and basic that I can't figure out how to make use of it in a more complex manner.  Or trying to make it flat as you suggested turns everything into a nightmare I eventually can't keep track of.  Are there any examples that you know of that shows how to do something this complex in a flattened manner because I would love to study it just to see what patterns and features are used to do such a thing.

Comment: ok I'm getting an error on the `updatedCategories[index].products = [...]` part is causing an error saying `Cannot assign to read only property 'products' of object '[object Object]'`.

Comment: G'day - yeah my sample code is not 100% perfect, wasn't able to test it when I posted this answer.  You need to deep clone the object at `updatedCategories[index]` so  you can modify the clone and push it back to the state.

Comment: IMO you will find the flatter structure much easier to handle (even if it seems counter intuitive at first, particularly if your API is returning nested parent/child structures). In my current app we have dozens of states and anywhere we didn't flatten (some of our earlier code) it has been difficult to maintain going forward.
If you could edit your question to include the State Model (to show this models/size etc) then I might be able to add more pointers

Comment: ok I've been stuck for a couple days on something else because this solution is somehow causing my `@Selector()` to return both the previous and current data to my component and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Saw that on your other question .. might be time to put up a StackBlitz that reproduces the error

Comment: Only thing is I'm using NestJS for my backend, which we can't use on stackblitz.  What's the best way to go about representing it in our stackblitz demo?

Comment: Best way is to replace your service class with a mock that returns dummy data in an Observable array